# PIC Microcontroller Environment VS Arduino Microcontroller Environment

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, pic, atmega, microchip

Does the PIC chip environment have any advantage against AtMega or Arduino Environment for low cost, low power regular use rather than being a little chip?

Yes, this is a broad question but I am having an argument with a co-worker on which chip to go with so need to settle a debate.

Comment: You are not comparing PIC to AtMega and Arduino. You are comparing Atmega and PIC to Arduino. Arduino is weak and slow but easy. PIC and Atmega, without Arduino is much more powerful.

Comment: If you're looking for low power, you might consider an ARM series, where you can disable clocking for each peripheral individually.

Comment: Depends on what you think is an advantage and it depends what you want to do with it. Unanswerable. Just because a PIC might have some feature and other chips don't, it really does not matter if it is an irrelevant for the task. So arguing with you coworker is unnecessary. Define what you need and then look at which chip can do it best, from different angles, such as hardware or software or price or how fast you need to do it or what tools you already have and are familiar with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, yes.  There's often a tradeoff between "easy" and "powerful".
My own opinion is that the Arduino environment is comparatively easy to use, but I feel that it hides a lot of the behind-the-curtain stuff that really unleashes the power of a microcontroller.  I think this is particularly true with interrupt programming, which I find pretty clunky in the Arduino environment.

This has zero to do with "low cost".  Dev time is a really tiny slice of true costs, especially in  a manufacturing scenario.

My experience is that you can program any chip in the Arduino space with a real compiler with really cheap hardware, so "which chip or dev board should I commit to" is also not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The MCU choice is very depends on the task, you need to perform. PIC series has a big amount of different MCUs and mostly they have similar core an commands. On one chip there is a lot of peripheral, includes analogs too. For simple tasks it good choice. But if you need to run, for instance, heavy calculation Arduino environment has more features and a lot programs, solutions. But sometimes ever that not enough. More powerful MSUs on market, like STM, Raspberry.